# Equivalent of sys.exit() of Python in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, sl4a

I m using SL4A to execute Python/Javascripts in Android. Can anyone let me know the equivalent of `sys.exit()` of Python in JavaScript? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this:

```
throw "stop execution";
```